# slide widget to right or left

Tags: android

I have ListView with several elements of type LinearLayout. How to make slide effect on they like as in the contacts(when a contact slide on the right then there is a call, in the other case message is written).

Comment: Have you tried by your own? I mean what you have tried yet?

Comment: using gestures u can find slide left or right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is view pager that your talking about
Here is an example that i have made for you

The ViewPageExample.java file

```
public class ViewPageExample extends Activity {

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private Context mContext;
private MyPageAdatper mAdapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
mContext = this;

mAdapter = new MyPageAdatper();
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.mViewPager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

private class MyPageAdatper extends PagerAdapter{


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
               //Since only contacts messages and call logs were mentioned by you
                return 3;
        }


        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View mView = null ;
            switch(position){
                case 0:
                    mView   =   inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts, null);  
                    Button btn1 = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
                    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                break;

                case 1:
                    mView   =   inflater.inflate(R.layout.messages, null);   
                break;

                case 2:
                    mView   =   inflater.inflate(R.layout.callogs, null);   
                break;
            }




                ((ViewPager) collection).addView(mView,0);

                return mView;
        }


        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
                ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
        }



        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                return view==((View)object);
        }


        @Override
        public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {}


        @Override
        public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {}

        @Override
        public Parcelable saveState() {
                return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void startUpdate(View arg0) {}

}


}
```

The activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#a4c639">
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/mViewPager"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The callogs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Call Logs"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The contacts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Contacts"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The messages.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SomeMessages"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thaks for your work. I trying to adapte your code for my program. Firstly I created resource file with definition of ViewPager- http://goo.gl/AFXjZ. Then I created MyPageAdapter.java file- http://goo.gl/VsEYT. Then in MainActivity.java I set custom ArrayAdapter(file- http://goo.gl/HKtGz) to ListView was defined in MainActivity file(http://goo.gl/Ha17M). When code in load_content method in a call to ArrayAdapter.getView that an error in inflate of event_itemlayout. Error: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070004 type #0x12 is not valid

Comment: I am not able to understand your code, some codes are not complete, Please share the project files(All of them as possible)

Comment: Not longer relevan, this work. Thanks)

Comment: ((ViewPager) collection).addView(mView,0); // is that correct? the position is zero for any view in the collection?

Answer (score 1):

you can use a view pager along with the list view

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/